# Add then immediately remove empty list item

Tags: jquery

I need to force redraw of a list, so I'm adding then removing an empty item:

```
 $('#region ul').append("<li></li>").remove("<li></li>");
```

However, this only adds the empty item to the end of the list and does not remove it...

Comment: Why do you need to redraw the list?

Comment: There is for sure better way to force UI redraw, e.g just calling `offsetHeight` on DOM element, check the net

Comment: @Oriol I'm using Phonegap and on a sony xperia device, some elements render with what looked like a blurred border, even though there is no border. When you redraw the element, it disappears. I have only seen this on the xperia device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`remove()` doesn't work that way. It wants to be called on the element you're removing:

```
$('<li></li>').
  appendTo('#region ul').
  remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#region ul').append("<li></li>")
$('#region ul li:last-child').remove();
```